# What user privilege is required by a user to be able to run a GRANT sql command in Oracle

Tags: oracle, sql-grant

I created a user "UserA" and granted it Create session, user, tablespace privileges.
Now logged in as "UserA", I have successfully created another user "UserB" but unable to run grant privileges to "UserB" with error: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges.
What privileges should "UserA" have to be able to run grant statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you currently have (I presume so, as you didn't post what you exactly did):

Connected as a privileged user (`sys`), I'm creating a new user who's being granted `create session` and `create user` privileges:

```
SQL> connect sys@pdb1 as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> select tablespace_name from dba_tablespaces;

TABLESPACE_NAME
------------------------------
SYSTEM
SYSAUX
UNDOTBS1
TEMP
USERS

SQL> create user usera identified by usera
  2  default tablespace users
  3  temporary tablespace temp
  4  quota unlimited on users;

User created.

SQL> grant create session, create user to usera;

Grant succeeded.
```

As `usera` has been granted the `create user` privilege, it is allowed to create a new user - `userb`:

```
SQL> connect usera/usera@pdb1
Connected.
SQL> create user userb identified by userb
  2  default tablespace users
  3  temporary tablespace temp
  4  quota unlimited on users;

User created.
```

But, granting `create session` fails because `usera` isn't allowed to do that:

```
SQL> grant create session to userb;
grant create session to userb
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges


SQL>
```

---

So, what can you do?

One option is to use the **`with admin option`**; back to `sys` and re-grant it to `usera`:

```
SQL> connect sys@pdb1 as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> grant create session to usera with admin option;

Grant succeeded.
```

Can `usera` now grant `create session` to `userb`? Yes!

```
SQL> connect usera/usera@pdb1
Connected.
SQL> grant create session to userb;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>
```

---

Another option is to grant **`dba`** role to `usera`:

```
SQL> connect sys@pdb1 as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
```

Revoking `create session` from `usera` will *cascade* to `userb` who can't create session any more:

```
SQL> revoke create session from usera;

Revoke succeeded.
```

Only `usera` has create session privilege:

```
SQL> grant create session to usera;

Grant succeeded.
```

But, grant `dba` as well

```
SQL> grant dba to usera;

Grant succeeded.
```

Can `usera` now grant `create session` to `userb`? Yes!

```
SQL> connect usera/usera@pdb1
Connected.
SQL> grant create session to userb;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>
```

---

**However**: note that both `with admin option` and `dba` are **powerful** and - if you don't pay attention - you might have a security hole in your system. Leave powerful privileges to powerful users only; all the others shouldn't be doing such tasks.